# Build an intersection matrix in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix, count, intersection

I have a set of students who have each selected a certain number of courses that they want to take next semester, represented as an array of hashes:

```
[
{"student"=>"1", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false},
{"student"=>"2", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true},
{"student"=>"3", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false},
{"student"=>"4", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true}
]
```

I want to build a matrix showing how many conflicts there are between each course, end result something like this:

```
        English Algebra History
English    2       1       1
Algebra    1       2       -
History    1       -       2
```

Where the number at the intersection is the number of students who have selected *both* courses, i.e., the number at the intersection of (English, English) is 2 = the total number of students who selected English. The number at (History, Algebra) is "-", because there is never a student who has selected both of those courses.

I tried looking at the ruby docs for the Matrix class and it seemed like that addresses more mathematical matrices- I'm not sure how to retool it for this purpose, or if it's an appropriate class for this problem.

What kind of approach could I try researching/googling to efficiently construct a matrix like this?

Comment: Are your hashes stored in an array?

Comment: Yes! They are actually read in from a csv as an array of hashes where each hash describes a specific student

Comment: You may wish to update your question to reflect this:)

Comment: Thank you! Done; I didn't want it to come across as just giving my problem to the community and waiting for an answer- clearly I fell on the wrong side of providing needed specifics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for any number of school subjects and any grouping size (i.e., not just `2`).

**Code**

```
def count_groupings(arr, group_size)
  combos = (arr.flat_map { |h| h.keys }.uniq - ["student"]).
    repeated_combination(group_size).to_a.product([0]).to_h
  arr.each do |h|
    keys = h.keys.select { |k| h[k] == true }
    combos.keys.each { |k| combos[k] += 1 if (k-keys).empty? }
  end
  combos     
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [
  {"student"=>"1", "English"=>true,  "Algebra"=>true,  "History"=>false},
  {"student"=>"2", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true},
  {"student"=>"3", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>true,  "History"=>false},
  {"student"=>"4", "English"=>true,  "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true}
]

count_groupings(arr, 1)
  #=> {["English"]=>2, ["Algebra"]=>2, ["History"]=>2}
count_groupings(arr, 2)
  #=> {["English", "English"]=>2, ["English", "Algebra"]=>1, ["English", "History"]=>1,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"]=>2, ["Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History"]=>2}
count_groupings(arr, 3)
  #=> {["English", "English", "English"]=>2, ["English", "English", "Algebra"]=>1,
  #    ["English", "English", "History"]=>1, ["English", "Algebra", "Algebra"]=>1,
  #    ["English", "Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["English", "History", "History"]=>1,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra", "Algebra"]=>2, ["Algebra", "Algebra", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "History", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History", "History"]=>2}
```

**Explanation**

See [Array#repeated_combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination).

The steps are as follows for `group_size #=> 2`.

```
a = arr.flat_map { |h| h.keys }
  #=> ["student", "English", "Algebra", "History", "student", "English",
  #    "Algebra", "History", "student", "English", "Algebra", "History",
  #    "student", "English", "Algebra", "History"]
b = a.uniq
  #=> ["student", "English", "Algebra", "History"]
c = b - ["student"]
  #=> ["English", "Algebra", "History"]
d = c.repeated_combination(group_size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["English", "Algebra", "History"]:repeated_combination(2)
e = d.to_a
  #=> [["English", "English"], ["English", "Algebra"], ["English", "History"],
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"], ["Algebra", "History"], ["History", "History"]]
f = e.product([0])
  #=> [[["English", "English"], 0], [["English", "Algebra"], 0],
  #    [["English", "History"], 0], [["Algebra", "Algebra"], 0],
  #    [["Algebra", "History"], 0], [["History", "History"], 0]]
combos = f.to_h
  #=> {["English", "English"]=>0, ["English", "Algebra"]=>0, ["English", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"]=>0, ["Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History"]=>0}
```

```
g = arr.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"student"=>"1", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false},
  # ... 
h = g.next
  #=> {"student"=>"1", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false}
i = h.keys
  #=> ["student", "English", "Algebra", "History"]
keys = i.select { |k| h[k] == true }
  #=> ["English", "Algebra"]
j = combos.keys
  #=> [["English", "English"], ["English", "Algebra"], ["English", "History"],
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"], ["Algebra", "History"], ["History", "History"]]
m = j.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["English", "English"], ["English", "Algebra"],
  #   ...]:each>
k = m.next
  #=> ["English", "English"]
(k-keys).empty?
  #=> (["English", "English"] - ["English", "Algebra"]).empty?
  #=> [].empty?    
  #=> true
combos[k] += 1
combos
  #=> {["English", "English"]=>1, ["English", "Algebra"]=>0, ["English", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"]=>0, ["Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History"]=>0}
```

```
k = m.next
  #=> ["English", "Algebra"]
(k-keys).empty?
  #=> (["English", "Algebra"] - ["English", "Algebra"]).empty?
  #=> [].empty?
  #=> true
combos[k] += 1
combos
  #=> {["English", "English"]=>1, ["English", "Algebra"]=>1, ["English", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra"]=>0, ["Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History"]=>0}
```

The remaining calculations are similar. If preferred, one could write

```
combos = (arr.flat_map { |h| h.keys }.uniq - ["student"]).
    repeated_combination(group_size).map(&:uniq).product([0]).to_h
  #=> {["English"]=>0, ["English", "Algebra"]=>0, ["English", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra"]=>0, ["Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["History"]=>0}
```

Note the initialization of `combos` for `group_size = 1`:

```
combos = (arr.flat_map { |h| h.keys }.uniq - ["student"]).
    repeated_combination(group_size).to_a.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {["English"]=>0, ["Algebra"]=>0, ["History"]=>0}
```

and for `group_size = 3`

```
combos = (arr.flat_map { |h| h.keys }.uniq - ["student"]).
    repeated_combination(group_size).to_a.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {["English", "English", "English"]=>0, ["English", "English", "Algebra"]=>0,
  #    ["English", "English", "History"]=>0, ["English", "Algebra", "Algebra"]=>0,
  #    ["English", "Algebra", "History"]=>0, ["English", "History", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "Algebra", "Algebra"]=>0, ["Algebra", "Algebra", "History"]=>0,
  #    ["Algebra", "History", "History"]=>0, ["History", "History", "History"]=>0}
```

**Alternative data structure**

If there is a choice of data structure, a hash may be easier to work with than the array of hashes given, and there is no need to include courses that student are not taking (especially when hundreds of courses are being taught).

```
courses_by_student = {
  1 => %w| English Algebra|,
  2 => %w| History |,
  3 => %w| Algebra |,
  4 => %w| English History |
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I'm going to use the docs to figure out how and why that combination of methods works.It looks like I could use the same code with a little modifcation to find intersections between triples' of courses as well, is that true?

The only thing this answer doesn't do is highlight when there are zero conflicts between course selections, is there a better way than just checking which pairs aren't already represented and assuming that they have a count of zero?

Comment: Yes on triples (or more). Just change `repeated_combination(2)` to `repeated_combination(n)`, where `n` is an argument of your method.  I don't know what you mean by "zero conflicts", but if a value is zero in the hash it means that no students are taking the pair of courses represented by the key for that value.

Comment: Thank you very much for expanding on your answer! Sorry, yes, by conflicts I meant when the count of students requesting that pair was 0. The final hash output doesn't appear to list the pairs where 0 students request that pair, e.g., (History, Algebra) -- these pairs are of special interest (it shows those classes can run at the same time) - is there an easy way to include those combinations in the output?

I'm working my way through your detailed step-by-step explanation, I'm so grateful for your help, especially being able to work through and understand how you solved it. Thank you!

Comment: I had omitted the pairs with zero counts, but I see why you need them. I've modified the code and will update the explanation. Be sure to look at David Hu's answer. It's quite nice and is more direct.

Comment: Thank you again, you've gone above and beyond

Comment: Following through the explanation line by line, I'm having trouble adapting this method for group sizes greater than two. Is it possible that
"
pairs.each { |sub1, sub2| h[[sub1, sub2]] += 1 if (g[sub1] && g[sub2]) } }.
"
compares pairs as a matter or structure, causing errors when calculations are made for larger group sizes?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll fix it now.

Comment: The process of working it through to try and troubleshoot was so valuable, it helped me figure out where I hadn't quite grasped the way that it's working. Thank you, I only raised the comment again because after hammering away for a few hours I couldn't quite explain what the problem was. I was thinking, possibly the method needs to generate an argument in the block ("g|sub1|....g|sub(n)|")

Comment: I did a major modification to my answer, both to fix it for `group_size` other than `2` and to clean up the code generally.

Comment: The way this works is really amazing, I was overwhelmed when you first made these modifications and I didn't post to thank you- thank you; studying how this is put together has helped me to learn a lot. I'm using the hash data structure you suggested, vast improvement

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful. It was interesting for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
{"student"=>"1", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false},
{"student"=>"2", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true},
{"student"=>"3", "English"=>false, "Algebra"=>true, "History"=>false},
{"student"=>"4", "English"=>true, "Algebra"=>false, "History"=>true}
]

classes = data.first.keys.reject { |class_name| class_name == "student" }
print ' ' * 10
classes.each { |class_name| print "#{class_name}".center(10) }
puts 
classes.each_with_index do |row_class_name, idx|
  print row_class_name.ljust(10)

  classes.each do |col_class_name|
    count = data.count do |hash|
      hash[row_class_name] && hash[col_class_name]
    end
    print count.to_s.center(10)
  end
  puts 
end
```

This will output

```
           English   Algebra   History  
English       2         1         1     
Algebra       1         2         0     
History       1         0         2
```

Comment: Nice, and you print the table as well! Note that you don't use `idx`. I'm guessing that's a relic of an earlier draft.

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing to see the different approaches to the same problem- I'm working through this slowly so that I completely understand it